# Higher dimension matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

Suppose I have:

1. **A**, a matrix of shape (m, 3). **A<sub>i</sub>** is the i<sup>th</sup> row of this matrix.
2. n matrices **S<sub>1</sub>**, ..., **S<sub>n</sub>**, each one of shape (3, 3)
3. n vectors **v<sub>1</sub>**, ..., **v<sub>n</sub>**, each one of shape (3, )

I want to calculate the matrix **M** of shape (m ,n), defined by:

**M<sub>ij</sub> = (A<sub>i</sub> - v<sub>j</sub><sup>T</sup>) S<sub>j</sub> ((A<sub>i</sub>)<sup>T</sup> - v<sub>j</sub>)**

How can I do it efficiently using NumPy, without iterating with Python loops over i and j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you actually have m vectors, you can stack all your vectors using [`np.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html), producing a (m, 3) matrix. You can then subtract that from A directly (literally using `-`) and transpose it for the last part (with [`ndarray.swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.swapaxes.html)). Call this X. S can also be stacked in a similar way, producing a (n, 3, 3) matrix. You can then use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to multiply them (by adding dimensions to X and S):

```py
V = np.stack(vs)
S = np.stack(Ss)

X = A - V
X = X[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]
S = S[np.newaxis, :, :, :]
M = X @ S @ X.swapaxes(2, 3)
M = M.squeeze((2, 3))
```

Edit: You can also do it using [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), but that may be a bit more complex depending on your background:

```py
M = np.einsum('ik,jkl,il->ij', X, S, X)
```

Edit 2: After reading the accepted answer, I realise I misunderstood the question. Rather than simply deleting my answer, here's the correct answer implemented using `np.einsum`:

```py
def using_einsum(A, S, V):
    X = A[np.newaxis] - V[:, np.newaxis]
    return np.einsum('jik,jkl,jil->ij', X, S, X)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately m and n can be different

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that m and n had to be equal, just that you probably meant m vectors, not n. But I see that may be wrong. Fun problem anyway!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to implement a solution only using numpy. First, I assume that your vectors v and matrices S are gathered into numpy arrays, respectively with shapes (n, 3) and (n, 3, 3).

If not, it is possible to concatenate vectors and matrices using np.concatenate:

```py
S = np.concatenate([s.reshape(1, d, d) for s in [s_1, s_2, ..., s_n]], axis=0)
V = np.concatenate([v.reshape(1, -1) for v in [v_1, v_2, ..., v_n]], axis=0)
```

I also assume that A is stored into a numpy array of shape (m, 3).

The naive implementation (using for loops) is the following:

```py
def naive(A, S, V):
    assert S.shape[0] == V.shape[0]
    M = np.zeros((A.shape[0], S.shape[0]))

    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(V.shape[0]):
            diff = A[i] - V[j]
            M[i, j] = np.dot(
                np.dot(
                    diff.reshape(1, -1),
                    S[j],
                ),
                diff.reshape(-1, 1),
            ).reshape(-1)

    return M
```

And the optimized one, only using numpy:

```py
def only_numpy(A, S, V):
    diff = A.reshape(m, 1, 3) - V.reshape(1, n, 3)
    return np.matmul(
        np.matmul(
            diff.reshape(m, n, 1, 3),
            S.reshape(1, n, 3, 3),
        ),
        diff.reshape(m, n, 3, 1),
    ).reshape(m, n)
```

We factorize the substraction using numpy broadcasting. We also use matmul to broadcast matrix multiplication ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68422297/batch-matrix-multiplication-in-numpy)).

We can verify that both function return the same result with:

```py
assert np.allclose(naive(A, S, V), only_numpy(A, S, V))
```

Concerning the optimisation, I ran some experiments. Assuming: d=3, and n=2*m. I have (*naive*, *only_numpy* and *einsum* columns report elapsed time in seconds, using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/how-do-i-measure-elapsed-time-in-python) or memory using [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) with default resolution):

```
% time in seconds
       n      m   naive (t)  only_numpy (t)  einsum (t)
0    100    100    0.185373        0.000584    0.000701
1   1000   1000   18.964981        0.044783    0.054029
2  10000  10000         N/A        4.228531    4.098396

% memory in MiB
       n      m  naive (m)  only_numpy (m)  einsum (m)
0    100    100       63.6            63.6        63.6
1   1000   1000      101.9           109.8       102.0
2  10000  10000        N/A          4689.3      3918.7
```

The einsum implementation is from [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11057932/david) (see the other answer).

Comment: It works, thank you! Can it possibly run faster using np.einsum as mentioned in @David's answer?

Comment: Your question interested me, so I compared this with a corrected version of mine. `np.einsum` tends to be a little faster when n and m are large (>=2000 on my computer). I can't go too high because of memory constraints, but testing at 10k x 10k it's takes 40% less time. Probably not worth it. However, if you run into memory constraints, `np.einsum` seems to use about 40% less memory. If you're running it repeatedly, you may be able to improve this with `np.einsum_path`.

Comment: Can you please explain how to implement this code using np.einsum?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Not sure if I should delete the rest of it, but anyway.